# VBA make Dropdown always visible Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I found this Code on the internet, it should make those little arrows from the dropdownmenu visible. This works, but I would like to make only the following cells visible:

**B2,B11,B12,B13**

```
Sub ShowArrowsExceptOne()
'shows all arrows except
' in specified field number
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim iHide As Long
Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1)
i = 1
iHide = 3 'leave this field's arrow hidden
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In rng.Cells
  If i = iHide Then
    c.AutoFilter Field:=i, _
      Visibledropdown:=False
  Else
      c.AutoFilter Field:=i, _
      Visibledropdown:=True
  End If
  i = i + 1
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried it the following way:
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iHide As Long
    i = 1
    iHide = 3 'leave this field's arrow hidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
With Intro.Range("B2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Visibledropdown:=True
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

But it always makes the dropdowns visible on **B1,C1 and D1**

Can anybody help me on this?

[image: The button I want to be visible]

Comment: I'm affraid I don't quite understand exactly what you want, can you mock up a screen capture of what you want?

Comment: @Sirmyself I will try give me a second

Comment: @Sirmyself it is this button i would like to be visible and the column "B2" is a dropdown list

Comment: Ok, so you want this button to show on B2, B11, B12, B13 and no other cells?

Comment: That code is for autofilter dropdowns, not data validation dropdowns. You can't do what you want with DV dropdowns - you would have to use controls (Form or, shudder, ActiveX) for the ones you want visible.

Comment: Is exactly as [@Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory) said. Filters and data validation dropwdowns are not the same. Filters only work in rows that are Headers of a range, and hide/show rows that matches the criteria applied. Data validation dropdowns affect 1 single cell, and are used to set the value of the cell itself, from a list. Each cell can contain their own data validation dropdown. So configure your sheet to show data validations only in cells B2,B11,B12,B13.

Comment: In other words, read and understand the code you're "finding online" before you use it. This question is unfortunately too broad for this site. Do a bit of research, you'll likely find what you're looking for right here on this site.